# Can't style SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

Help please, I'm relatively new to coding and wanna learn to make website. I am trying to insert a menu button like the one you see from the SVG but can't figure out how to style it . This is my first time using an SVG. I followed a youtube video on how to do this but still no luck :( Thanks in advance to anyone that replies.

```css
body {
  background-color: #edf0f1;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(252, 25, 29, 1) 1%, rgba(201, 0, 3, 1) 50%, rgba(132, 3, 12, 1) 100%);
  border-bottom: solid 1.5px #000;
}
header h3 {
  float: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10.5px;
  color: #fff;
}
header button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 95%;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
header button svg .fill {
  color: #fff;
}
.light {
  font-weight: lighter;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h3>Practise <span class="light">Website</span></h3>
  <button>
    <svg height="32px" id="Layer_1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32px" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <path class="fill" d="M4,10h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2s-0.896-2-2-2H4C2.896,6,2,6.896,2,8S2.896,10,4,10z M28,14H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2  s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2S29.104,14,28,14z M28,22H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2  S29.104,22,28,22z"
      />
    </svg>
  </button>
</header>
```

Comment: What kind of styling are you looking to do?

Comment: `svg`s do not have the *normal* CSS attributes, they have their own. A full list can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute). You are probably looking for `fill` and `stroke`.

Comment: @tbirrell Simply make it white with a black stroke

Comment: So white background and black icon?

Comment: I got it working :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [`fill`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/fill/) property instead of `color`.

```
header button svg .fill {
    fill: #fff;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #edf0f1;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(252, 25, 29, 1) 1%, rgba(201, 0, 3, 1) 50%, rgba(132, 3, 12, 1) 100%);
  border-bottom: solid 1.5px #000;
}
header h3 {
  float: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10.5px;
  color: #fff;
}
header button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 95%;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
header button svg .fill {
  fill: #fff;
}
.light {
  font-weight: lighter;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h3>Practise <span class="light">Website</span></h3>
  <button>
    <svg height="32px" id="Layer_1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32px" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <path class="fill" d="M4,10h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2s-0.896-2-2-2H4C2.896,6,2,6.896,2,8S2.896,10,4,10z M28,14H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2  s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2S29.104,14,28,14z M28,22H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2  S29.104,22,28,22z"
      />
    </svg>
  </button>
</header>
```

**Per @Ricky**

> SVG elements should be cleaned before using them on the web. Attributes such as `enable-background` and some xml attributes are not necessary when adding the SVG inline in HTML.

Also, there are [other SVG specific CSS properties available](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html) to you beyond `fill`.

Comment: You need to define the exact styling you want, which you didn't do in your question. The above answer makes the hamburger icon white instead of black. Which is what I had to assume from your code.

Comment: I updated my CSS selector to match yours, and added Stack Snippet, please try now.

Comment: I was doing more trouble shooting and removed the gap between svg and .fill and forgot to change it back. When I changed it back and tried the suggestion, it worked :)

Comment: Lol, that would do it. `svg.fill` would target the wrong element.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to use the [fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes) css property, not color.

```
header button svg .fill {
  fill: #fff;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8dunb4wo/)

Comment: I was doing more trouble shooting and removed the gap between svg and .fill and forgot to change it back. When I changed it back and tried the suggestion, it worked :)